# problem with itertools permutations in combination with english_words_set in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, set, python-itertools

I want to get all possible words with 5,6,7 characters from a random string: `word="ualargd"`

I do the following:

- A for loop to change the length of my permutations.

```
for i in range(5,len(word)+1):
    mywords=permutations(word, i)
```

- The items created by the permutation get compared with an english dictionary set.

This works fine as long as i dont use the for loop.

The for loop creates the permutations `mywords` correctly. Once it contains strings like "aura" with 4 letters in the next loop "gudar" with 5 letters...

But unfortunately as soon as my loop leaves the first loop no word gets found anymore in the english dictionary. How come? If i replace the i value by hand in `mywords=permutations(word, i)` everything works fine.

```
#output     #expected output
5           5   
neeld       neeld
dense       dense
leden       leden
neele       neele
neese       neese
needs       needs
6           6
7           lendee
            needle
            selene
            lensed
            sendee
            7
            needles
```

The code for reproduction looks like this:

```
from itertools import permutations
from english_words import get_english_words_set

word="dseeenl"
web2lowerset = get_english_words_set(['web2'], lower=True)

for i in range(5,len(word)+1):
    print(i)
    mywords=permutations(word, i)
    for item in set(mywords):
        word=''.join(item)
        if word in web2lowerset:
            print(word)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different variable name in the loop other than `word`, because you overwrite your original starting word

```
from itertools import permutations
from english_words import get_english_words_set

word="dseeenl"
web2lowerset = get_english_words_set(['web2'], lower=True)

for i in range(5,len(word)+1):
    print(i)
    mywords=permutations(word, i)
    for item in set(mywords):
        w=''.join(item)
        if w in web2lowerset:
            print(w)
```

Comment: lol me dumb. ty! Wow everything makes sense now

Comment: Happens to everyone;)